# CSP Headers - refused to apply a stylesheet in safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, http-headers, httpresponse, content-security-policy

I added some CSP headers for my site.

```rb
  config.csp = {
    default_src: %w('self' https: wss:),
    base_uri: %w('self'),
    child_src: %w('self' https:),
    font_src: %w('self' data: https:),
    frame_ancestors: %w('self'),
    img_src: %w('self' data: https:),
    object_src: %w('self'),
    script_src: %w('self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https:),
    script_src_elem: %w('self' 'unsafe-inline' https:),
    script_src_attr: %w('self' 'unsafe-inline' https:),
    style_src: %w('self' 'unsafe-inline' https:),
    style_src_elem: %w('self' 'unsafe-inline' https:),
    style_src_attr: %w('self' 'unsafe-inline' https:),
    worker_src: %w('self' blob:)
  }
```

But for some reason i get next error in console, **only in Safari**, meanwhile in other browsers it's ok.

`Refused to apply a stylesheet because its hash, its nonce or 'unsafe-inline' does not appear in the style-src directive of the Content Security Policy`

How can i fix it?